# How to remove Ubuntu 15 and GRUB bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, windows-10

I want to uninstall Ubuntu from my laptop as well as GRUB bootloader. My laptop is currently dual-booting windows 10 and ubuntu.FYI I don't have any windows installation disk. Is there any way I can completely remove Ubuntu as well as grub bootloader? Thanks a lot for your feedback, I really appreciate it.

Comment: This might help ... http://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows

Comment: If you have BIOS/MBR install, then answer below works. If you have UEFI, you just need to choose to boot Windows by default in UEFI settings. And you can remove UEFI NVRAM settings & /EFI/ubuntu folder: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu  But if using Windows you must create a Windows repair flash drive and keep it updated if you get a newer version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Great care. If you delete Ubuntu the computer does not start.

Before deleting it, you should restore Windows 10 boot record deleting Grub.

The command in Windows 10 is `bootsect.exe`

```
bootsect /nt60 drive_letter: /mbr
```

This fixes boot record of partition mapped to `drive_letter` and the `MBR` of the Windows installed disk.

```
C:\Windows\system32>bootsect
bootsect {/help|/nt60|/nt52} {SYS|ALL|<DriveLetter>:} [/force] [/mbr]
Boot sector restoration tool
```

Restart the system in Windows, you can delete the Ubuntu partition with Windows Disk Quick Tools.